# windows batch script to enter password automatically in a console

Tags: batch-file

followed instructions given in below link to configure automatic backup from linux to windows

https://www.gefoo.org/rsync-your-backup-files-from-a-linux-box-to-a-windows-box.html

created a batch file to backup from Linux to windows machine using certificates which doesn't require password. this is working on four linux machines

but one linux machine is asking for password, need a script which automatically enters password in to the console.

so that i can schedule it with task scheduler.

tried auto-it recording but it is not running when screen locked.

how to enter password automatically using a batch file ??

Comment: Would you mind adding things like these: `.` or  those `,`? Additionally any code you have would be useful!

Comment: Capitalization would be great as well.

Comment: I am too lazy to read this question...

Comment: @aschipfl - I don't even see a question here.

Comment: @SomethingDark, me neither, there are no question marks...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using keys to auth and have it working from one machine but another machine is asking for the password, it either does not have the key or the passphrase for the key was never correctly entered.

Comment: followed instructions given in this link https://www.gefoo.org/rsync-your-backup-files-from-a-linux-box-to-a-windows-box.html

Comment: checked & compared permissions on .ssh folder & authorized_keys file. which is same on other machines. also checked this machine's entry exists in known hosts file on windows with other machines.

Comment: If this is the case you have either a problem with SSH itself or the keystore provider.